# How to run a .jnlp file in ubuntu server

Tags: java

I am trying to run a `.jnlp` (java) file in Ubuntu Server. This file is BitCoin minter. When I try to run it, it says access is denied.

Comment: Set the files permission to executable and run it again.

Comment: From personal experience, it works on desktop versions of Ubuntu 18.04LTS. My son's online school uses a lot of java for live classes. it works!

Answer (score 60):

Using the [Iced Tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IcedTea)

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx
```

followed by

```
javaws ~/Downloads/cgoban.jnlp
```