# Run JNLP (Java Network Launching Protocol) file on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, java, icedtea

I am new to Ubuntu 20.04 (or say any version).

I recently upgraded my PC from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.

While in Ubuntu 18.04 I was able to login to my company from file *.jnlp.
Required Java version 1.8.

However, after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, I am not able to login to my company now.

I am not sure what steps to be taken to run the JNLP file and login.

Comment: Could you try `sudo apt -y install icedtea-netx icedtea-plugin` and after that `javaws yourfile.jnlp`and edit your post with the results?

Comment: ashish221@ashish221:~$ sudo apt -y install icedtea-netx icedtea-plugin
[sudo] password for ashish221: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package icedtea-plugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  icedtea-netx-common

E: Package 'icedtea-plugin' has no installation candidate

Comment: The solution is right there in the text. Use `sudo apt -y install icedtea-netx-common icedtea-plugin` instead of the first command I suggested.

Comment: Please add output of `update-java-alternatives -l` and `which javaws` to the question

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new
for Emk2203
ashish221@ashish221:~$ sudo apt -y install icedtea-netx-common icedtea-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'icedtea-netx' instead of 'icedtea-netx-common'
Package icedtea-plugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  icedtea-netx-common

E: Package 'icedtea-plugin' has no installation candidate

Comment: ashish221@ashish221:~$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64

Comment: I had a typo in there. I meant to do `sudo apt -y install icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common`. Please try again.

Comment: ashish221@ashish221:~$ sudo apt -y install icedtea-netx-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'icedtea-netx' instead of 'icedtea-netx-common'
icedtea-netx is already the newest version (1.8-0ubuntu8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

Comment: Java1.8 is required for running application

Comment: What happens now with `javaws yourfile.jnlp`?

Comment: ashish221@ashish221:~$ javaws NomuraConnect.jnlp
selected jre: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_261/jre/
Unable to use Firefox's proxy settings. Using "DIRECT" as proxy type.
netx: Invalid jnlp file NomuraConnect.jnlp



File is saved in desktop. Do I need to change location of file before running it.

Comment: You can try, but with the error being `netx: Invalid jnlp file NomuraConnect.jnlp`, it finds the file. Looks more like some incompatibility. Someone with more knowledge of jnlp workings needs to chime in.
Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473970/icedtea-version-1-8-is-unable-to-open-any-jnlp-file for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for help... I hope someone else can help me with command to correct setup in Ubuntu20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a .jnlp file in ubuntu server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565016/how-to-run-a-jnlp-file-in-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score 9):

The current package you need to install for `.jnlp` to run is:

```
sudo apt install icedtea-netx
```